# paypal sandbox returns internal error

Tags: paypal

I need to test our online store application with paypal sandbox. The testing used to work just fine for us. Then we did not touch it again for sometime. We made some changes recently and i needed to test the ordering flow again. paypal sandbox returns following every time i try -

> ERROR CODE 10001 Short Message
>   Internal Error Long Message Internal
>   Error

Our ordering flow -

1. SetExpressCheckout
2. GetExpressCheckoutDetails
3. DoExpressCheckoutPayment

There is a warning that started coming up in logs recently in case of sandbox (not in production) -
Warning :

> org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase - Cookie rejected:
>   "$Version=0;
>   X-PP-SILOVER=name%3DSANDBOX3.API.1%26silo_version%3D1880%26app%3Dappdispatcher_apit%26TIME%3D792388439%26HTTP_X_PP_AZ_LOCATOR%3Dsandbox.slc;
>   $Path=/; $Domain=.paypal.com". Domain attribute ".paypal.com" violates
>   RFC 2109: host minus domain may not contain any dots

We haven't changed anything around how system interacts with paypal sandbox. 
I looked it up and found some suggestion around turning negative testing on/off in sandbox account settings in their guide. But could not find any setting like that when i logged in.

I have yet to try another suggestion related to the warning but i am not sure if the warning is causing this issue -

```
System.setProperty("apache.commons.httpclient.cookiespec", "COMPATIBILITY")
```

Did anybody else face this issue? any help or guidance is much appreciated.